# Bootstrap TouchSpin, change the initval

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the initval(the actual value displaying in the TouchSpin) but it seems that there is no way to do it. I know you can change almost all values like the max value, so tried doing something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
$("input[name='touchspin']").TouchSpin({initval: 1}); //doesn't work
$("input[name='touchspin']").trigger("touchspin.updatesettings", {max: 100}); // change the max value, works.
$("input[name='touchspin']").trigger("touchspin.updatesettings", {value: 1}); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually find the solution searching other stuff on google

```
$("input[name='touchspin']").val(1); //if for example your spinner have 55 actual value, this will reset it to 1
```